# Problem with running Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 18.04, fsck

I installed Ubuntu on a flash drive yesterday. The installer said that everything was fine and offered to reboot. Done. Then the problems started. I got three options for starting the system.

1. The system starts loading and the error `fsck exited with source code 4` occurs. I found a solution on the Internet: enter the command `fsck-y /dev/sdb1` (in my case). Done.

   [Video demonstration](https://youtu.be/TmdkaVkczZ4): 1:27

   This short video demonstration starts at a black screen with a few lines of illegible text, then continues to the GRUB boot menu, and finally it continues to a solid black screen with no text and ends there.
2. The error which follows immediately after the first error (in the video the first error has failed to show the second).

   [image]

   [image]

   The first two lines appear first. After the Ubuntu logo appears and everything seems to work, but after everything else appears and nothing else happens on the last line. I tried to wait.
3. I made another [screencast](https://youtu.be/nNG2GXoGDmY).

   This screencast is a repeat of the first screencast, blurry text, grub menu and it ends at a solid black screen with no text.

Comment: The solution of this question was to wait for fsck to finish working.

Answer (score 0):

For the first look I would say you have bad/dead sectors on your flash drive. Can you install the system on another drive?

Comment: Thanks, I already solved the problem. The thing was that I did not wait for fsck to finish working. I thought it was only necessary to confirm everything and at that moment everything would be corrected. I was wrong